# Play Framework 2.1 (Java) eBean @Encrypted Annotation Errors

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm trying to use the eBean @Encrypted annotation on a String field for the database model.  The documentation makes it seem simple enough, but I'm getting a very vague runtime error in the browser for the following sample standard code using the built-in H2 in-memory database:

```
package models; 

import java.util.*; 
import javax.persistence.*; 
import play.db.ebean.*; 
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder; 
import play.data.format.*; 
import play.data.validation.*; 
import com.avaje.ebean.*; 
import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.*; 

@Entity  
public class Test extends Model { 

 @Id 
 public Long id; 

 @Encrypted 
 public String identifier;

}
```

Produces the following runtime error related to the @Encrypted annotation:

```
Unexpected exception
RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.Test
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.Test
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readInitial(ReadAnnotations.java:26)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createDeployBeanInfo(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1026)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentInitial(BeanDescriptorManager.java:533)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:250)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:210)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)
     com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:59)
     play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:79)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:63)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:62)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:133)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
     scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication.get(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
     play.core.server.Server$class.sendHandler$1(Server.scala:56)
     play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:88)
     play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:87)
     scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
     play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:87)
     play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:34)
     play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:103)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)
     org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
     org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455)
     org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538)
     org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:472)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:333)
     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
     org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
     org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have the encryptionKeyManager settings configured properly in the config (ebean.encryptKeyManager="com.avaje.tests.basic.encrypt.BasicEncyptKeyManager"). Everything compiles fine without any issues or even warnings as well.

I've even tried adding eBean 2.7.1 as a dependency manually in the project to no avail.

Any idea what this means and why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace (from logs) to have causes? Thanks!

Comment: Per the answer I provided below (which I think is the right one), the stack trace showed this which helped me narrow in on what was happening in the framework: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Using encryption on models.Test.identifier but no EncryptKeyManager defined!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I may have resolved this issue, but in a very roundabout way.  Problem is, the Play Framework cannot resolve the BasicEncryptKeyManager class in the EBean package.  I found this out when I viewed the entire stack trace as I was seeing the message "No EncryptKeyManager defined" even though I explicitly specified it in the settings file(s) (application.conf, ebean.conf, ebean.properties - you name it, I tried it) per the official documentation.

So, I had to create my own from scratch using the **ServerConfigStartup** as seen below (please note, this is just a quick and dirty example, may not be the most secure or efficient way of doing it):

```
package models;
import com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig;     
import com.avaje.ebean.event.ServerConfigStartup;     
import com.avaje.ebean.config.EncryptKey;       
import com.avaje.ebean.config.EncryptKeyManager; 

public class CustomServerConfigStartup implements ServerConfigStartup { 

    @Override 
    public void onStart(ServerConfig serverConfig) {     
          serverConfig.setEncryptKeyManager(new BasicEncryptKeyManager());     
    }     
} 

class BasicEncryptKeyManager implements EncryptKeyManager{ 

 @Override 
 public EncryptKey getEncryptKey(String tableName, String columnName) {     
       return new CustomEncryptKey(tableName, columnName);     
 } 

 @Override 
 public void initialise() { 
     //Do nothing (yet)
 } 

} 

class CustomEncryptKey implements EncryptKey{ 

   private String tableName;

   private String columnName;

   public CustomEncryptKey(String tableName, String columnName){
      this.tableName = tableName;
      this.columnName = columnName;
   }

 @Override 
 public String getStringValue() {     
        return play.Configuration.root().getString("application.secret") + "::" + this.tableName + "::" + this.columnName;      
 }     
}
```

Then in **application.conf** or **ebean.properties** file in the conf directory of the Play application (this step is probably redundant, however):

```
ebean.encryptKeyManager="models.BasicEncryptKeyManager"
```

This appears to resolve the @Encrypted annotation errors.  It appears that Play will have to incorporate an accessible EncryptionKeyManager class in the actual framework for Ebean in some future version to avoid this workaround.

Comment: care to answer this post? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435718/ebean-manual-decryption

Comment: I recently stumbled across this answer - so far it's workingg great - however - This approach uses no initialization vector. As a result the same content will lead to the same encrypted content. An is thus vulnerable to XOR attack. Is there any solution on how to add an init vector?

Comment: There are several ways to do that using the available methods in the EncryptKeyManager and ServerConfigStartup interfaces. You should start by researching those.