# Ebean manual decryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have successfully setup encryption for a field in my model using the answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800453/play-framework-2-1-java-ebean-encrypted-annotation-errors) SO post. But I would like to know how to manually decrypt the field from SQL client for debugging purposes. I want this information for Mysql (Prod database) and preferably for H2 (dev database). As per E-bean documentation Mysql uses AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT and H2 uses ENCRYPT/DECRYPT functions.

```
  @Encrypted
  @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(50)")
  public String password;
```

Note: I have set the datatype of encrypted field as varchar instead of binary as shown below. Hence Ebean might additionally Hex the generated binary data.

```
class CustomEncryptKey implements EncryptKey{ 

   private String tableName;
   private String columnName;

   public CustomEncryptKey(String tableName, String columnName){
      this.tableName = tableName;
      this.columnName = columnName;
   }

 @Override 
 public String getStringValue() {     
        return "my-encryption-key";     
 }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to Identify the answer. For My-SQL

to decrypt:

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(encrypted-field,'my-encryption-key') as CHAR(50)) from table
```

to encrypt:

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(encrypted-field,'my-encryption-key') from table;
```

For H2:

encrypt:

```
ENCRYPT('AES', STRINGTOUTF8('<encryption-key>'), STRINGTOUTF8('<text to be encrypted>'))
```

decrypt:

```
TRIM(CHAR(0) FROM UTF8TOSTRING(DECRYPT('AES', STRINGTOUTF8('<encryption-key>'), '<text to be encrypted>')))
```